# Multiple property query in MongoDB using Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongoDB & Mongoose.

I would like to query in my collection of the string provided by the user is contained in either of the two property I have on each document so for example:

query string is :"ar"

{
firstName:"Mark",
lastName:"Sashloe"
},

firstName:"Kevin",
lastName:"Charloom"
}

in my proposed query, both documents should be catched since the firstName property of the first document contains "ar" and the lastName property of the second document has it too.

Comment: You can use `$or` in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as Cuong Le Ngoc said you can use $or and also $regex

[how to use regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/)

[how to use or](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/)

```
var search="ar";
yourCollectionSchema.find({ $or: [{firstName: { $regex: '.*' + search+ '.*' } },lastName: { $regex: '.*' + search+ '.*' }] })
```